# SetText in realtime when writing on EditText

Tags: android

In an Android app, I have an `EditText` and a `TextView`. I would like to put the content of the EditText in the IextView in real-time when the user writes something in the EditText.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have really tried doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a text change listener:

```
yourET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            yourTV.setText(yourET.getText().toString());
        }
});
```